# Visual Studio 2010 project conversion to Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, migration, csproj

I have a bunch of solutions in my company that I need to convert and make compatible with VS2012 (keeping framework 4.0, btw).
I tried opening them with 2012 directly, an the converter made a couple of changes in the .csproj files.

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
```

and below:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
</PropertyGroup>


<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
```

Could anybody tell me what exactly these changes mean? I tried googleing it with no luck.

Plus, do I have any risk if I tried to rollback the .csproj to the previous version and leave it as it is?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each Visual Studio project is basically a big build script (you can actually use msbuild to build your project files from the command-line). What the converter is doing is pulling in the correct build properties for the new version of Visual Studio you're using. You could actually go look at the files it's pulling in as they are located on your local computer.

The first change you posted is pulling the correct version of `Microsoft.Common.props` (common build properties) needed by Visual Studio 2012. This import is in your old project, too, just a different version.

The second change is importing all the necessary build "targets" (msbuild calls executable blocks of script "Targets") to build web applications.

If you're paranoid, sure, keep a backup of the old project but to be honest I don't see anything alarming in the above changes - they are just there to pull in the correct supporting files for the build engine.

I hope that helps! I worked with project files and msbuild for years and can give you a more detailed explanation if you need it.

Comment: Thank you SO much, Mr. Spock. I already marked your answer as the accepted one. But if you have any details of why it changed (or maybe a link), that'd be great. Thanks again!

Comment: Every time Microsoft rolls Visual Studio they increment the version number. For instance, I think VS2008 was version "9.0" and VS2010 was version "10.0." Each of these Visual Studio versions has build files associated with that specific version. The changes in your project file(s) are there so the build engine will pick the correct supporting files (assemblies, build targets, etc.) for the version of Visual Studio you're using. You wouldn't want to have a VS2012 project source older build infrastructure - they may (and probably are) NOT compatible.

Comment: I tried out VS 2015, so it did an automatic upgrade, saying that it had made "non-functional changes" to the project. But we are using VS 2010, so it broke the build on our build server, changing

<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />

To this:

<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />

Comment: This is the error I was getting on the build server: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\fdef323deb26dbe9\Solutions\MyProj.csproj(2534, 3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
Project Solutions\MyProj.csproj failed.